# FindCycle with EdgeWeight in directed graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Following up on the discussion in [Problem with EdgeWeight and FindCycle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124452/problem-with-edgeweight-and-findcycle), consider the simple directed graph:

```
graph = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2,
               2 \[DirectedEdge] 3,
               3 \[DirectedEdge] 1,     
               3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 }, 
               EdgeWeight -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 0,
                              2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> -1,
                              3 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 1,    
                              3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 1 },
                EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: A simple directed graph]

Note this graph has two circuits of length 0: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 and 2 -> 3 -> 2

```
FindCycle[graph,0]
```

returns:

```
{{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1}}
```

It only finds one of the two cycles. Is the "all" in

> For weighted graphs, FindCycle[g,k] gives **all** cycles with total weights less than k.

incorrect as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's the documentation, not the implementation that has the issues.

```
FindCycle[graph,0,All]
```

returns both cycles.

Changing the graph so that 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 has total weight -1:

```
graph = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2,
               2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
               3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
               3 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
              EdgeWeight -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> -1, 
                             2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> -1,
                             3 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 1, 
                             3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 1}, 
               EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: graph with a negative weight circuit]

and invoking FindCycle:

```
FindCycle[graph,0]
```

again returns

```
{{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1}}
```

a circuit of total weight -1

```
FindCycle[graph,0,All]
```

returns both circuits.

It appears the documentation should read

> For weighted (directed) graphs, FindCycle[g,k] gives some cycle(s) with total weight less than or equal to k. FindCycle[g,k,All] gives all cycles with total weight less than or equal to k.